# How to read files from to make objects of a class?

Tags: c++, file, class, vector, stream

The assignment is as follows:

Create a class named Student with data members for all of the following fields:

```
Id
Exam 1 Grade
Exam 2 Grade
Homework Grade 
Final Exam Grade
```

This class should define a member function named `calcTotalGrade` for calculating and returning the total grade based on the following equation:

```
Total Grade = 0.20 × Exam 1 + 0.20 × Exam 2 + 0.35 × Homework + 0.25 × Final Exam
```

It should also define a member function named `calcLetterGrade` for determining the student’s letter grade from the total grade based on the following breakdown:

```
A: >= 90
B: < 90 and >= 80
C: < 80 and >= 75
F: < 75
```

The main() function should open a file named `grades.txt` preview the document (which can be downloaded from under Files/assignments; save it into your assignment folder) and read it into a vector named students, In other words, read the input file line by line, and for each line (except for the headers line) do the following:

1. Create a Student object containing the information in the line.
2. Add this object to the vector students.
3. Finally, iterate over the students vector and create a table with the following fields to a file named `students.txt`.

   ```
   Id: 10 places; left-justified (HINT: use the left manipulator)
   Exam_1: 12 places; right-justified (HINT: use the right manipulator)
   Exam_2: 12 places; right-justified
   Homework: 12 places; right-justified
   Final : 12 places; right-justified
   Total: 12 places; right-justified; rounded to 2 decimal places (HINT: use the fixed and setprecision(2) manipulators)
   Letter Grade: 15 places, left-justified
   ```

---

This is the code I have so far based on some assignment guide

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>
    #include <iomanip>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    class Student{
        private:
        string id;
        int exam1, exam2, hwrk, final;
    
        public:// Constructor
        Student() {}
        Student(string id, int exam1, int exam2, int hwrk, int final) :
            id(id), exam1(exam1), exam2(exam2), hwrk(hwrk), final(final){}
        
        // Accessors and mutators
        const string getId() const { return id; }
        void setId(int id){ this->id = id; }
        
        int getExam1() const { return exam1; }
        void setExam1(int exam1){ this->exam1 = exam1; }
        
        long getExam2() const { return exam2; }
        void setExam2(int exam2){ this->exam2 = exam2; }
        
        int getHwrk() const { return hwrk; }
        void setHwrk(int hwrk){ this->hwrk = hwrk; }
    
        int getfinal() const { return final; }
        void setfinal (int final){ this->final = final; }
        
        
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Student& s){
            out << "ID: " << s.id << '\n'
                << "EXAM_1: " << s.exam1 << '\n'
                << "EXAM_2 " << s.exam2 << '\n'
                << "HOMEWORK " << s.hwrk<< '\n'
                << "FINAL" << s.final << '\n';
                // << "TOTAL GRADE" << s.calcTotalGrade()<< '\n'
                // << "LETTER GRADE" << s.calcLetterGrade() << '\n';
            return out;
        }
        
        // Destructor
        ~Student(){}
        
        int calcTotalGrade(){
            int Total_grd = 0.20 * exam1 + 0.20 * exam2 + 0.35 *hwrk + 0.25 * final;
            return Total_grd;
        }
    
        char calcLetterGrade(int Total_grd){
            char let_grd;
            
          if (Total_grd >= 90){
              let_grd = 'A';
            }
              else if(Total_grd >=80 & Total_grd<90){
                  let_grd ='B';
              }
              else if(Total_grd >=75 & Total_grd<80){
                    let_grd = 'C';
                }
                  else{
                      let_grd = 'F';
                  }
                 
        return let_grd;}
        };

main(){
        ifstream fin("grades.txt");
    
    vector<Student> students(5);
    fin >> students[0] >> students[1] >> students[2] >> students[3] >> students[4];

for(string s : students) {
    cout << s << " ";
}
```

Comment: Check your textbook on what the `>>` operator does and how to implement it for user-defined classes

Comment: Well, you missed `friend istream& operator>>(istream& out, Student& s)` you also could put that `fin >> student` in a loop, "&" is not correct, replace all with "&&", and  if the value passed as false in Total >= 90 you dont need to check if it Total is <90 just after. You may also put your code in https://godbolt.org/ to help SO people check and change it. Simple members doesn´t need setters/getters, just make the fields public. You don't need trivial constructors , just use https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization instead

Comment: being advised that no operator matches these operands when attempting to collect the object data in `` friend istream& operator>> (istream& in, const Student& s){
       in >> s.id >> s.exam1 >> s.exam2 >> s.hwrk >> s.hwrk; return in;
    }` ` I was getting this with a previous assignment as well but I can't tell why.

Comment: @CleitonSantoiaSilva I'm still having difficulties with the istream operator reassignment. Any tips?

Comment: What kind of problems exactly you still have ? You can post your implementation online in https://godbolt.org/ using a stringstream as input ( insted of a file ) like this https://godbolt.org/z/ccMc9T